# rollup-plugin-dts leaves leftover d.ts files

Tags: typescript, rollup, .d.ts

Very trivial problem it seems. I have a rollup typescript config using rollup-plugin-typescript and rollup-plugin-dts. I want to bundle all my d.ts files into one d.ts file instead of having it mirroring my project structure. I followed some tutorials and ended up with the configs below.

The problem: dts() bundles the file correctly but leaves the original build structure as is. None of my resources addresses this. Shouldn't the now obsolete input files be deleted? Am I handling the plugin badly?

Where I start:

```
dist/
├── index.js 
├─ dts //I compile my types into here, below is my mirrored project structure
    ├── components
    │   ├── Button.d.ts
    │   ├── index.d.ts
    ├── index.d.ts
```

What I want:

```
dist/
├── index.js 
├── index.d.ts //everything bundled here
```

Unfortunately what I get:

```
dist/
├── index.js 
├─ dts //All of this is still here, it shouldn't be
    ├── components
    │   ├── Button.d.ts
    │   ├── index.d.ts
    ├── index.d.ts
├── index.d.ts //It bundled correctly to this additional file though
```

tsconfig.json

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "allowJs": true,
    "allowSyntheticDefaultImports": true,
    "declaration": true,
    "declarationDir": "dts",
    "downlevelIteration": true,
    "esModuleInterop": true,
    "forceConsistentCasingInFileNames": true,
    "isolatedModules": true,
    "jsx": "react-jsx",
    "lib": ["dom", "dom.iterable", "esnext"],
    "module": "esnext",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "noEmit": true,
    "noFallthroughCasesInSwitch": true,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "resolveJsonModule": true,
    "skipLibCheck": true,
    "sourceMap": true,
    "strict": true,
    "target": "es5",
    "strictFunctionTypes": true
  },
  "include": ["src/"],
  "exclude": ["node_modules", "build", "dist", "src/stories/**", "**/*.stories.ts", "**/*.test.ts", "**/*.test.tsx"]
}
```

rollup.config.js

```
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

export default [
    {
        input: './src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/index.es.js',
                format: 'es',
                exports: 'named',
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            typescript({
                tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
            }),
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
            }),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            external(),
            terser(),
        ],
    },
    {
        input: './dist/dts/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
        plugins: [dts()],
    },
];
```

Answer (score 6):

I also recently faced a similar issue and was able to come up with a nifty solution with a few additions to the config file. I'm adding stuff to your file only. For the solution, I used [rollup-plugin-delete](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-delete) package. Basically we have to remove the  `dts` folder once the build is complete.

```js
import babel from 'rollup-plugin-babel';
import resolve from '@rollup/plugin-node-resolve';
import external from 'rollup-plugin-peer-deps-external';
import { terser } from 'rollup-plugin-terser';
import commonjs from '@rollup/plugin-commonjs';
import dts from 'rollup-plugin-dts';
import typescript from '@rollup/plugin-typescript';

// Added this
import del from "rollup-plugin-delete";


export default [
    {
        input: './src/index.ts',
        output: [
            {
                file: 'dist/index.js',
                format: 'cjs',
            },
            {
                file: 'dist/index.es.js',
                format: 'es',
                exports: 'named',
            },
        ],
        plugins: [
            typescript({
                tsconfig: './tsconfig.json',
            }),
            babel({
                exclude: 'node_modules/**',
                presets: ['@babel/preset-react'],
            }),
            resolve(),
            commonjs(),
            external(),
            terser(),
        ],
    },
    {
        input: './dist/dts/index.d.ts',
        output: [{ file: 'dist/index.d.ts', format: 'es' }],
        plugins: [
            dts(),
            del({ hook: "buildEnd", targets: "./dist/dts" }), //<------ New Addition
        ],
    },
];
```

In the `tsconfig.json` file, its mentioned that the declaration typefiles should be outputted to `dts` folder. Depending on how one export types from `index.ts` file, types will be declared and exported in `dts/index.d.ts` via the typescript transpilation process. This folder may have other files as well. Using [rollup-plugin-dts](https://www.npmjs.com/package/rollup-plugin-dts), it combines all the exported and needed types from `dts/index.d.ts` to a single file definition file `index.d.ts` in `dist` folder. Once this process is complete, we want to delete the `dts` file. For that, we use `rollup-plugin-delete` plugin, which gives us access to [rollup build hooks](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#build-hooks). Here we want to delete `dts` folder once the build process is complete; for that we use [buildEnd](https://rollupjs.org/guide/en/#buildend) hook, along with target folder name. This will ensure that `dts` folder is deleted once rollup has finished bundling.

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.

Comment: @AbhishekDutt I've added more context to the solution.

Comment: @ShubhamSingh This fixed the same problem I had and I can confirm it works! Thanks